# Is there a way to use Mongoose middleware with the query builder?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm using mongoosejs in a trusted environment (aka what's passed is always considered safe/prevalidated) and I need to pass it "select" and "populate" stuff on potentially every query I run.  I'm getting this in a consistent manner for every request.  I want to do something like this:

```
var paramObject = sentFromUpAbove; // sent down on every Express request
var query = {...}
Model.myFind(query, paramObject).exec(function(err, data) {...});
```

The function I would pass to the middleware or other construct is simple, just:

```
function(query, paramObject) {
  return this.find(query)
    .populate(paramObject.populate)
    .select(paramObject.select);
}
```

And the same for a findOne.  I know how to do this by directly extending Mongoose, but that feels dirty.  I'd rather use middleware or some other construct that does this in a clean and somewhat future proof way.

I'm aware that I can accomplish this via statics on a model by model basis, but I'd like to do it universally on every model.  Any advice?

Comment: So apparently, adding to the prototype is the way to do this.  Dirty or not I guess it's time to dive in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488712/mongoose-nested-ref-models-population), but unfortunately find operations do not call `pre` and `post` so they skip middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a simple Mongoose [plugin](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) that adds `myFind` and `myFindOne` functions to any schema you wish to apply it to:

```
// Create the plugin function as a local var, but you'd typically put this in
// its own file and require it so it can be easily shared.
var selectPopulatePlugin = function(schema, options) {
    // Generically add the desired static functions to the schema.
    schema.statics.myFind = function(query, paramObject) {
        return this.find(query)
            .populate(paramObject.populate)
            .select(paramObject.select);
    };
    schema.statics.myFindOne = function(query, paramObject) {
        return this.findOne(query)
            .populate(paramObject.populate)
            .select(paramObject.select);
    };
};

// Define the schema as you normally would and then apply the plugin to it.
var mySchema = new Schema({...});
mySchema.plugin(selectPopulatePlugin);
// Create the model as normal.
var MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', mySchema);

// myFind and myFindOne are now available on the model via the plugin.
var paramObject = sentFromUpAbove; // sent down on every Express request
var query = {...}
MyModel.myFind(query, paramObject).exec(function(err, data) {...});
```