# Mongoose: nested ref models population

Tags: node.js, data-structures, mongoose

How can I populate nested referenced models?

For example:

```
// 'Collection' model
var CollectionSchema = new Schema({
  collection_name: String,
  _groups: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }],
});

// 'Group' model
var GroupSchema = new Schema({
  group_name: String,
  _item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }  // To be populated
  _meta: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Meta' } // To be populated
});

// 'Item' model
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  item_name: String,
  item_description: String
});

// 'Meta' model
var MetaSchema = new Schema({
  meta_name: String,
  meta_value: String
});
```

I'd like to populate each "_item" inside "_group" in "Collection" models.
I mean getting something like this:

```
{
 collection_name: "I'm a collection"
 _groups: [ 
           { _id: ObjectId("520eabd1da5ff8283c000009"),
              group_name: 'Group1',
              _item: { _id: ObjectId("520eabd1da5ff8283c000004"),
                        item_name: "Item1 name",
                        item_description: "Item1 description"
                    },
             _meta: {
                       _id: ObjectId("520eabd1da5ff8283c000001"),
                      meta_name= "Metadata name",
                      meta_value = "metadata value"
                    }
            },
            { _id: ObjectId("520eabd1da5ff8283c000003"),
              group_name: 'Group2',
              _item: { _id: ObjectId("520eabd1da5ff8283c000002"),
                        item_name: "Item2 name",
                        item_description: "Item2 description"
                    },
             _meta: {
                       _id: ObjectId("520eabd1da5ff8283c000001"),
                      meta_name= "Metadata name",
                      meta_value = "metadata value"
                    }
            }
          ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Group = mongoose.model('Group', GroupSchema);
Group.find().populate('_item').populate('_meta').exec(function (error, groups) {
  //groups will be an array of group instances and
  // _item and _meta will be populated
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I would rather do

```
var Group = mongoose.model('Group', GroupSchema);

Group.find().populate('_item _meta').exec(function (error, groups) {
  // ...
});
```